# How to share single 3G dongle network connection over a LAN which is connected via cable

Tags: networking, 3g, dongle

I have a 3G dongle. What I can do is that I use this dongle on single PC. but I want to share this in my office on multiple computers. It is possible?

I am using windows 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the other computers are Windows machines they can use your internet connection through a feature called [Internet Connection Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing).

1. Open **Network Connections** by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking **Control Panel**. In the search box, type 'adapter', and then, under **Network and Sharing Center**, click **View network connections**.
2. Right-click the connection that you want to share, and then click **Properties**. If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
3. Click the **Sharing** tab, and then select the **Allow other network users to connect through this computer’s Internet connection** check box.

[Full article here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7).

---

For a small LAN an alternative solution is to replace your router with one that has a USB port and 3G modem support - this way all connected machines will then be able to share the internet connection transparently.

Answer (score 0):

Note: you need a network connection as dynamic ip configuration with IP4

Step 1: please install **connectify hotspot pro** (download from here: http://www.connectify.me/).

step 2: Reboot your computer.

step 3: insert your 3g/2g dongle to the computer and connect the internet.

step 4: open your connectify hotspot.

step 5: In the **connectify prompt**, set the **internet** share as "**automatic**"

step 6: In "**advance settings**"-set the "**share over**" as **wifi** or **Ethernet controler** (acording to your wish     you can change where you have to share your internet)

step 7: Hit the start hotspot button and enjoy